how to register open generic types with concreted parameter in C#
we can do dependency injection on open generic types as:
public interface IRepo<T, TKey> where T: class { ... }

public class RepoBase<T, TKey>: IRepo<T, TKey> where T: class {...}

// DI
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepo<,>), typeof(RepoBase<,>));  

but I want to make RepoBase to have two open type and one concrete type as:
public interface IRepo<T, TKey> where T: class { ... }

public class RepoBase<T, TKey, D>: IRepo<T, TKey> where T: class {...} where D : DbContext  // D is DbContext from EF 
{
   ...
}  

public class MyDbContext : DbContext { ... }

services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepo<,>), typeof(RepoBase<,,>));  // compiles, but what I want is the third type should be MyDbContext

services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepo<,>), typeof(RepoBase<,,MyDbContext>)); // doesn't compile, but this is what I want

so how can I register open generic type but provide partial concrete type?

Just so that someone has said it: You probably shouldn't have either anyway. Assuming we are talking about Entity Framework Core, that is your generic repository.

You may be able to follow the pattern of having two types - T<A, B, C> and T<A,B> : T<A, B, CConcrete>. Look at asp.net identity classes for examples of doing this to apply "default" type arguments.

If we only ever have MyDbContext - do we need it as a type arg, though? Either that's not what OP actually needs / wants or it is superfluent, no? (Different story if OP were to build a library, so that there actually could be different XyzDbContext.)

@Damien_The_Unbeliever could you show me an example code from  asp.net identity, thank you

@Damien_The_Unbeliever are you referring to MakeGenericType ?
https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.cs,70    this is still not what I want, I want the some argument types to be "any" type

No, I mean look at e.g. the types in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore. There are base types with lots of type parameters and then derived classes that fix one or more of those types whilst still being generic in other ways.

As mentioned already in comments, you could define such type:
public class RepoBaseWithMyContext<T1, T2> : RepoBase<T1, T2, MyDbContext>

and then register it like:
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepo<,>), typeof(RepoBaseWithMyContext<,>));

